# PhD article: Structure to compare results of two algorithms

Tags: publications, phd, thesis

First of all, please accept my apologies if I commit any mistake when asking my question, but it's my first one on this vibrant community.

I am finishing my PhD, and I am writing an article to publish soon. Basically, this is the picture:

**-There is an algorithm, "A", that is 4 years old.**

**-I created an algorithm, "B", that improves "A" in a %**

I think the following scheme may reflect the investigation, but;

*Do you feel this is a good skeleton for the article?*

```
1. Introduction
2. Definition of the problem
3. Investigation goals
4. Classic Algorithm Description
5. Improved Algorithm Description
6. Results
7. Conclusions and discussion
```

Comment: looks reasonable to me (without knowing any specifics).  this is a journal article related to the PhD dissertation and not the dissertation itself, right?

Comment: I'm not sure what "Investigation goals" means. Perhaps it can be pushed into the introduction.

Comment: Thanks a lot first of all to both for the feedback. @robertbristow-johnson its a journal article related to it, not the dissertation itself. user2768, I'll bear it in mind, thanks

Comment: As "A" is already 4 years old, I would expect to also see a comparison of your algorithm to other improved versions of "A" that might have appeared in the meantime, or at least some _related work_ section that will at least show that you are aware of them.

Comment: Does this look like the skeleton of other well-written journal articles describing similar results (describing an x% improvement to an k-year-old algorithm) in your subfield? If so, this is a great structure.  If not, you should consider a different structure closer to the norm in your subfield.  If you don't know, then you really need to read more papers.

Comment: @JeffE Thanks for your point of view. The field is software engineering, will try to look for a similar paper